# StackingClassifier final_estimator grid search

Tags: scikit-learn

I am using a StackingClassifier using a RandomForest and BaggedLogisticRegression as first layer `estimators`, and a LogisticRegression for the `final_estmator`. I run a RandomizedSearch using the following params:

```
params = {
    
    'random_forest__max_depth': [3, 7, 10],
    'random_forest__n_estimators': [100, 150],
    
    'logreg_bagged__base_estimator__max_iter': [10000],
    'logreg_bagged__base_estimator__C': [10000, 20000, 100000],
    'logreg_bagged__base_estimator__class_weight': [{0: neg, 1: pos} for neg, pos in 
                                                        [(1 - ((val + 1) * 0.01), (val + 1) * 0.01) for val in range(5)]
                                                   ],
    'final_estimator__max_iter': [10000],
    'final_estimator__C': np.logspace(-4, 4, 4),
    'final_estimator__class_weight': [{0: neg, 1: pos} for neg, pos in 
                                                        [(1 - ((val + 1) * 0.01), (val + 1) * 0.01) for val in range(5)]
                                                   ],
}
```

the random_forest and logreg_bagged params run as expected, but I can't seem to access the final_estimator parameters to include them in the hyperparameter tuning. Does anyone know of a way to include that into the search space?

This are the model diagrams:
[Model_diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVNdY.png)

Comment: This looks right.  What isn't working?  MRE?

Comment: @BenReiniger I'll try and update with an MRE. Have you used GridSearch and StackingClassifier before and know that this is the proper way to handle the final_estimator params?

Comment: You should be able to call the StackingClassifier's `get_params` to double-check.